# hibernate jsonb type after save makes some ordering

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

```
 @Type(type = "jsonb")
@Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
private Map<String, String> businessHours;
```

this is field I set some map to it which keys are Sunday and Monday for example
,but after save in db i get Monday and Sunday order ,I need to keep it under Sunday Monday order how can I handle it?
even after save order is okay like i wanted but in db i see different order

Comment: The order of the keys in a JSON value is irrelevant

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name

Comment: then why it changes the order?

Comment: `jsonb` normalizes the representation to allow for better storage and more efficient processing. As the order of keys is irrelevant, changing that order has not impact on the actual value

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the `json` type as per the [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html), if you want to preserve the order of object keys:

> In general, most applications should prefer to store JSON data as jsonb, unless there are quite specialized needs, such as legacy assumptions about ordering of object keys.

Postgres internally sorts & indexes the data stored as jsonb so that it is faster to run operations on it. You can check https://bitnine.net/blog-postgresql/postgresql-internals-jsonb-type-and-its-indexes/ for more info.

You can change it to:

```
    @Type(type = "json")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "json")
    private Map<String, String> businessHours;
```

You can refer https://fullstackdeveloper.guru/2020/05/29/how-to-map-json-data-in-postgresql-database-to-a-hibernate-entity-column/ for more info.

Comment: yeah that's fine but can't declare JsonType.class

Comment: it is red so can't understand what JsonType.class is

Comment: @JackNickelson try using JsonStringType.class instead and see if that helps.

Comment: i agree but after using setter giving some map and then saving it ,it gives this error ERROR: column "business_hours" is of type json but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.